# Looping through a show and hide function in jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, loops, each

I am trying to show and hide text on a site. But I have to loop through an xml file and get all the elements. I am terrible at explaining so here it is on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/liveandream/3P2b6/

It is not working for each individual element. When you click on read more it makes both go down, and on close makes both go back up. The number of results I will get is almost impossible to know. I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @AshleyDavies In most cases they have to be; the browser will always stop at the first matching ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/3P2b6/3/

Fixed it for you. Probably not as optimised as it can be, but should work fine.

Comment: You might want to adjust your HTML a bit so there's less "parent" and "children" calls in jQuery, but it shouldn't make too much of a difference.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're attaching the click function to `#read2` and that there are two elements with id `read2`. Note that an element should have a unique id in a document but that's a different discussion.

Whenever you click on an element, it should find the element to collapse or close. For example, when I click on `read1` it should open or close `amenities1` and when I click on `read2` it should open or close `amenities2`. This means you'll have to rename the ids and classes for this to work.

You can get the number by doing the following: when an element is clicked, get its id as a string and get the number from that string. Then, construct the id or class of the element that you wish to open or close (by doing `amenities` + number) and open / close it.

Answer (score 0):

How about this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3P2b6/2/)**? The only change to the HTML I made was making the IDs unique (the first read2 is now read1).

jQuery:

```
$(".amenities").hide();
$('.readMore').click(function() {
    if ($(this).next().is(':visible')) {
        $(this).next().hide();
        $(".arrow",this).html("►");
    } else {
        $(this).next().show();
        $(".arrow",this).html("▼");
    }
});​
```

HTML:

```
<div class="amenitiesWrap">
    <div class="readMore" id="read1"> <span class="arrow">►</span> See Room Amenities</div>
    <div class="amenities"><p>Donec mollis imperdiet lacus ut rhoncus. Pellentesque tincidunt leo vitae mauris varius ut mattis erat condimentum. Donec non tellus ut augue rutrum dignissim vitae eu nibh. Nunc vitae lacinia lectus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed quis placerat dolor. Morbi tempus tellus quis eros iaculis posuere. Vivamus a risus nisl. Quisque non turpis massa, vitae mollis urna. Etiam placerat quam eget purus pellentesque rhoncus commodo lorem placerat. Ut in justo enim. Mauris vitae sem eros. Ut aliquam bibendum nulla quis posuere. Maecenas est quam, scelerisque adipiscing laoreet sed, lobortis ac eros. Donec consectetur augue vel nunc rutrum vestibulum.<br />
<div class="closeAmenities">Hide Amenities</div></p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="amenitiesWrap"><div class="readMore" id="read2"> <span class="arrow">►</span> See Room Amenities</div><div class="amenities"><p>Donec mollis imperdiet lacus ut rhoncus. Pellentesque tincidunt leo vitae mauris varius ut mattis erat condimentum. Donec non tellus ut augue rutrum dignissim vitae eu nibh. Nunc vitae lacinia lectus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed quis placerat dolor. Morbi tempus tellus quis eros iaculis posuere. Vivamus a risus nisl. Quisque non turpis massa, vitae mollis urna. Etiam placerat quam eget purus pellentesque rhoncus commodo lorem placerat. Ut in justo enim. Mauris vitae sem eros. Ut aliquam bibendum nulla quis posuere. Maecenas est quam, scelerisque adipiscing laoreet sed, lobortis ac eros. Donec consectetur augue vel nunc rutrum vestibulum.<br />
<div class="closeAmenities">Hide Amenities</div></p></div></div>​
```